# C# I wanna know only childnode's (file) full path

Tags: c#, treeview, filepath

I showed my own computer's directory with the `treeview`. I need only childnodes (file)'s full filepath (I meant file's filepath not parentnodes (file folder's directory.)

If I click the parentnode and something important is in that parentnode sometime has parentnode.

I don't need a Parentnode (filefolder)'s filepath.

I really have no idea how I can get a filepath of childnode (file directory).

I already know how to get fullpath.

```
private void C_B_treeView_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{

  if ((e.Node.Checked) && (e.Node.StateImageIndex == 1) && (C_R_treeView.SelectedNode == null))     
  {
        ///////////source is needed here//////////////////
        }//if Parentnode, 

        else//if I click the just file node(not root node)
        {
            ftp_filePath = e.Node.FullPath;
            AL_ftp_filepath.Add(ftp_filePath.ToString());
        }

        if (e.Node.Checked == false)
        {
            for (int i = AL_ftp_filepath.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if(AL_ftp_filepath[i-1].ToString().Equals(e.Node.FullPath)){
                    AL_ftp_filepath.RemoveAt(i-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path.aspx) class be helpful for this?

Comment: TreeNode.Text Property?

Comment: I already know how to know fullpath. I wanna know only childnode(file)'s full path, if I click the parent node.

Comment: @Jozef Benikovsky I already know how to get fullpath. What I wanna know is another problem.

Comment: When you want to have the child Nodes Path when clicking on a parent Node you should define from which ChildNode you want the path. A node can have multiple childs.

Comment: @Ralf I need every childnode. and I wanna know how to define everychildnode.